# Using Response.Redirect() to a relative path

Tags: asp.net

I'm working with ASP.net. My website is hosted within a subfolder `test` under the IIS root directory. So the url of default.aspx is `http://localhost/test/Default.aspx`. From default.aspx, I want to use `Reponse.Redirect()` with a relative path to redirect to another url within the same web site, `http://localhost/test/whatever`.

I tried

```
Response.Redirect("/whatever");
```

and

```
Response.Redirect("~/whatever");
```

Both of them redirect to `http://localhost/whatever`. Note that the `Redirect` method use  `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost/test/` as the base url.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I made a silly mistake myself. Response.Redirect("~/whatever"); should go to http://localhost/test/whatever. Thank you all .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
Response.Redirect("hello");
```

also

```
Response.Redirect("./hello");
```

Enjoy!

Comment: not working bro

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if I'm over-simplifying or misunderstanding your question, but have you simply tried:

```
Response.Redirect("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your application is not hosted in the directory test, it is instead hosted in the directory above it.  If you want the ~ (aka tilde) to work, you need to make test the virtual path to your application, at which point your host really will be hosted in test and Response.Redirect("~/whatever") will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (my example is VB.net)

```
  Dim url As String = "~/SomeDirectory/SomePage.aspx"
  Response.Redirect(url.Replace("~"c, Request.ApplicationPath))
```

I like to have Utils.RedirectRelative("~/SomeDirectory/SomePage.aspx") in a class somewhere but I don't know how "good practice" that is.